# Extracting tag from bs4.element.tag returns empty string

Tags: python, html, json, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract all of the answers from a Quora url following a tutorial. my code looks like this

```
url = 'https://www.quora.com/Should-I-move-to-London'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
answers = soup.find("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"})
answers
```

However, when I try to get the text from the answers (bs4.element.tag object),
it just appears as empty.
How can I extract all of the answers?
I also tried the following

```
data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)
```

But I am getting the following error

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I attached a screenshot with the structure of the bs4 body.[image]

Comment: I just tried your script and the line: `data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)` worked fine for me

Comment: I tried ..but I get the same error as OP

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.string` to get the object.

Here's how:

```
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.quora.com/Should-I-move-to-London').content, 'html.parser')
answers = soup.find("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"})
data = json.loads(answers.string)
print(data["mainEntity"]["answerCount"])
```

For example, this prints:

```
12
```

To print the answers use this:

```
for number, answer in enumerate(data["mainEntity"]["suggestedAnswer"], start=1):
    print(f"Answer: {number}. | Upvote count: {answer['upvoteCount']}")
    print(answer["text"].strip())
    print("-" * 80)
```

Comment: Is this different than my answer? What are you adding?

Comment: Look who posted the answer first. :-]

Comment: How do you print the answers to the question?

Comment: @AbrarAhmed I've upadted the answer.

Comment: Now the answer is complete.

Comment: `for number, answer in enumerate(data["mainEntity"]["suggestedAnswer"], start=1):
    print(f"Answer: {number}. | Upvote count: {answer['upvoteCount']}")
    print(answer["text"].strip())
    print("-" * 80)` ..just beautiful!!..Salut.

Comment: @baduker Interesting, I thought I posted my answer first, but the timeline proves me wrong. Either way +1 for adding extra details in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `.string` method:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.quora.com/Should-I-move-to-London'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
answers = soup.find("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"})

json_data = json.loads(answers.string)
```

```
>>> print(type(json_data))
<class 'dict'>
```